# SQL Query - group by more than one column, but distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a bidding table, as follows:

```
SellID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SellItem(SellID),
CusID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(CusID),
Amount FLOAT NOT NULL,
BidTime DATETIME DEFAULT getdate()
```

Now in my website I need to show the user the current bids; only the highest bid but without repeating the same user.

```
  SELECT CusID, 
         Max(Amount) 
    FROM Bid 
   WHERE SellID = 10 
GROUP BY CusID 
ORDER BY Max(Amount) DESC
```

This is the best I have achieved so far. This gives the CusID of each user with the maximum bid and it is ordered ascending.   But I need to get the BidTime for each result as well.  When I try to put the BidTime in to the query:

```
  SELECT CusID, 
         Max(Amount), 
         BidTime 
    FROM Bid 
   WHERE SellID = 10 
GROUP BY CusID 
ORDER BY Max(Amount) DESC
```

I am told that *"Column 'Bid.BidTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."*

Thus I tried:

```
  SELECT CusID, Max(Amount), BidTime 
    FROM Bid 
   WHERE SellID = 10 
GROUP BY CusID, BidTime 
ORDER BY Max(Amount) DESC
```

But this returns all the rows. No distinction. Any suggestions on solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, assuming another way of thinking about it is to return the LATEST bid by each user:

```
SELECT b.cusID, b2.LatestBidTime, b.Amount 
FROM Bid b
    JOIN (
        SELECT cusID, MAX(BidTime) AS LatestBidTime
        FROM Bid
        WHERE SellID = 10
        GROUP BY cusID) b2 ON b.cusID = b2.cusID AND b.BidTime = b2.LatestBidTime
WHERE b.SellID = 10
```

Comment: The error and such implies that the OP wants the bidtime for the max bid value, but I'm looking for clarification on that.

Comment: This works :) But i need to brush up my knowledge on joins...
As AdaTheDev was the first to answer, i assume it is fair to mark his answer as the accepted. However OMG Ponies gave a wonderful explanation too :)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
  SELECT b.cusid,
         b.amount,
         b.bidtime
    FROM BID b
    JOIN (SELECT t.cusid,
                 t.sellid,
                 MAX(t.amount) AS max_amount
            FROM BID t
           WHERE t.sellid = 10
        GROUP BY t.cusid, t.sellid) x ON x.max_amount = b.amount
                                     AND x.cusid = b.cusid
                                     AND x.sellid = b.sellid
ORDER BY b.amount DESC
```

Using aggregates means you can not get information at that given value in the same query.  You have to associate a copy of the table with the aggregated data (joins are the typical choice) to get the related information.

Comment: This is incorrect and could cause records to be excluded, since it is getting the highest bid for a `cusid` across **all** `sellid`s. If the same `cusid` has bid on more than one `sellid`, and they bid higher on a `sellid <> 10`, the `group by` will return that higher value which will not match anything in `b` due to the restrictive where clause, resulting in that row being filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.*
from Bid b
inner join (
    SELECT CusID, Max(Amount) as MaxBid
    FROM Bid 
    WHERE SellID=10 
    GROUP BY CusID 
) bm on b.CusID = bm.CusID and b.Amount = bm.MaxBid
where b.SellID = 10
ORDER BY b.Amount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the highest bid was made most recently, right? So just put `MAX` on `BidTime` too.

```
SELECT CusID, Max(Amount), MAX(BidTime)
FROM Bid 
WHERE SellID=10 
GROUP BY CusID ORDER BY Max(Amount) DESC
```

Comment: The MAX(bidtime) isn't guaranteed to be associated with the MAX(amount) value.

Comment: That would be the obvious case, but unfortunately i do not validate whether the bid to be made is higher than the current highest bid.

Comment: Most bidding systems do not let you submit new bids lower than previous ones, so it's not always an invalid assumption.

Comment: Yes i completely agree and it is and should definitely be the case.